# What is the optimal way to wait for multiple futures in C++11?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am looking for the optimal way in terms of execution time, to wait for independent futures to finish.

Dealing with only two futures is simple, one can have the optimal way as follows:

```
auto f1 = async(launch::async, []{ doSomething(’.’); }); 
auto f2 = async(launch::async, []{ doSomething(’+’); });

while (f1.wait_for(chrono::seconds(0)) != future_status::ready && f2.wait_for(chrono::seconds(0)) != future_status::ready) 
{ };

f1.get();
f2.get();
```

This way, we leave the loop while with at least one of the futures is finished, then calling `.get()` for both won't make the program looses time.

How about n futures?

Comment: I imagine that you imply that there is meaningfull work being done inside of that `while()` loop, and it's not just a busy wait, right? Otherwise, this would make no sense to me.

Comment: yes, inside the loop i can put this_thread::yield();

Comment: But how is agressively doing nothing better than letting your thread suspend and free up CPU while waiting for `get()` to return?

Comment: For the time being I am focussing on how can I wait without loosing time. I am looking for a way in the case of n(>2) futures, if you can help me with a better way in the case of n=2, you are welccome.

Comment: The waiting time is the same (both futures run in the background) my while loop does not affect their execution times

Comment: That's probably because you have more cores available than the number of threads invovled, or that the async tasks are so quick as to be irrelevant. There is nothing to be gained by forcefully forcing the re-scheduling of your main task, unless you are dealing with a somewhat exotic thread scheduling setup

Comment: If you have N things to wait for, waiting for all of them can be accomplished this way: 1. wait for the first one 2. wait for the second one. ... N wait for the Nth one. There's no need for busy-wait loops, yields, checks, or any of that nonsense..

Comment: @n.m.: So assume there's additional work to be done after each one finishes.  If the second one completes first, sequential wait misses the opportunity to start processing its results while the first future is still pending.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's not waiting for *all*, that's waiting for *any*. A totally different task.

Comment: @n.m.: I can't tell from this unclear question whether OP is interested only in "WaitAll" or also "WaitAny".

Comment: @BenVoigt The net result of posted code is identical to that of sequential wait, so I guess it's wait all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an arbitrary number of `std::futures`, it might help to put them all into a `std::vector`.  You can then loop through the vector and `get` the results.  Note that `get` handles waiting.

```
//Result type defined here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async
template<typename F, typename... Args>
using AsyncResult = std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<F>(std::decay_t<Args>...)>;

template<typename T, typename F1, typename F2>
void do_par(const std::vector<T>& ts, F1&& on_t, F2&& accumulate) {
  //The standard doesn't require that these futures correspond to individual
  //threads, but there's a good chance they'll be implemented that way.
  std::vector<std::future<AsyncResult<F1, T>>> threads;
  for (const T& t : ts) { threads.push_back(std::async(on_t, t)); }
  for (auto& future : threads) { accumulate(std::move(future)); }
}

template<typename T, typename F>
std::vector<AsyncResult<F, T>> map_par(const std::vector<T>& ts, F&& on_t) {
  std::vector<AsyncResult<F, T>> out;
  do_par(ts, on_t, [&](auto&& future_){ 
    out.push_back(future_.get()); //Think of this as just waiting on each thread to finish.
  });
  return out;
}

std::string doSomething(const std::string&){ return std::string("yo"); }
```

And then you can do

```
const std::vector<std::string> results = map_par(
  std::vector<std::string>{".", "+", "et al"}, doSomething
);
```

---

This simple `map_par` function isn't quite the savviest solution.  It might help to set up a thread queue (which itself would own a thread pool) to cut out the overhead of spawning individual threads, as well as the context-switching overhead which comes into play when you have more threads than CPU cores.  Your thread queue implementation might want to have its own `async` method, akin to `std::async`.

If you want to use results immediately when they come in, regardless of input order, consider setting up a single-reader-multiple-writer (which incidentally also involves a queue).

`std::condition_variable` helps with both of the above suggestions.